# How to pass variable from webpage javascript to node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post

I have a variable in Javascript that I'm trying to pass to node js so that it can be put in a JSON file but it is not writing to the file. I think have made a mistake in either the AJAX Post request or in the node JS routing.

The javascript running on a HTML page

```
   function WriteToJSON() {
    var floors = document.getElementById("floor-number").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/getfloors",
        dataType :"text",
        data: {Floors: floors},
    })
    }
```

The Node JS

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const { Router } = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

 app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/welcome-page.html'))
 })

 app.get("/Question-1", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/Question-1.html'))
})

app.post("/getfloors", (req, res) => {
  var floors = req.body.Floors;
  console.log(floors);
  fs.writeFileSync('Data.json', floors);
})

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using AJAX instead of the fetch method?

Try this solution (note, that I've used async function):

```js
async function WriteToJSON() {
    const floors = document.getElementById("floor-number").value;

    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.append("Floors", floors);
    
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/getfloors', { method: 'POST', body });
}
```

Comment: The instructions I found said to use AJAX but I will give the fetch method a go, do I need to add anything to the Node JS? I'm pretty new to this whole thing.

Comment: Your solution has not worked, I don't get any output in the console and nothing gets written to the JSON data file. Is there more to this that I need to do?